# Using capybara to select a button without an id or value

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, capybara

I don't know how to click on a button that has no id or value.

I've already tried using the xpath and selector paths but neither worked for me.

```
<div class="button js-vehicle-section-next full-width mb1">Next Step: Select a Repair</div>
```

Is the code for the button on the site. My current attempts are.

```
find('js-vehicle-section-next').click
click_on('js-vehicle-section-next')
find_all(:xpath, "//*[normalize-space(text())='Next Step: Select a Repair'").first.click
```

The expected result is that the button will be clicked

Comment: You need to use `.js-vehicle-section-next`, it's a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`click_on` clicks link or button elements so it’s not going to work here because you are trying to click a `div`. Instead you can just use a valid CSS selector and call `click` on the returned element

```
find(‘.button.js-vehicle-section-next’).click
```

If you didn't have a specific class for the next "button" and you needed to do it by the contained text you could do

```
find('div.button', exact_text: 'Next Step: Select a Repair').click
```